# uhashable type:DataFrame error when trying to write DataFrame to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have this code block that reads a named range from excel into a dataframe. Once I have that, I'm trying to upload it to a SQL table called projects. but I keep getting the following error:

```
    if key in metadata.tables:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame
```

Any ideas? Code block below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import sqlalchemy

projects_info = data_frame_from_xlsx_range(fileloc,'projects_info')


user = 'root'
pw = 'test!*'
db = 'hcftest'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:3306/{db}"
                          .format(user=user, pw=pw, db=db))

projects_info.to_sql('projects', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1496, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ExerciseFiles\ExerciseFiles\Chap01\sqlupdate.py", line 92, in <module>
    update_table(engine, projects_info, projects_info)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\ExerciseFiles\ExerciseFiles\Chap01\sqlupdate.py", line 90, in update_table
    newdata.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2987, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 695, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1728, in to_sql
    table = self.prep_table(
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1621, in prep_table
    table = SQLTable(
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 805, in __init__
    self.table = self._create_table_setup()
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1102, in _create_table_setup
    return Table(self.name, meta, *columns, schema=schema)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 277, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 432, in __new__
    return cls._new(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 462, in _new
    if key in metadata.tables:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback please?

Comment: I would guess that in this line `newdata.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)`, `table_name` is a dataframe, not a string.

Comment: oh man - I had put a stop before that line, but it looks like line but i messed up and only stopped part of that code. Stupid mistake. Thank you!